# How to jump to a ledger-report by key

Tags: spacemacs, ledger

This keybind **only works after I've opened a ledger file**.

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "jL"
  'ledger-report
  )
```

Thus I presume `ledger-mode` is required. Yet adding `(require 'ledger-mode)`

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "jL"
  (require 'ledger-mode)
  'ledger-report
  )
```

returns

```
kbd: Wrong type argument: integer-or-marker-p, ledger-report
```

`ledger-report`: https://github.com/ledger/ledger-mode/blob/3495d1224ee73aa96c1d5bd131dc3a7f23d46336/ledger-report.el#L264

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about spacemacs, but on general principles I would try this:

```el
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "jL"
  (lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (require 'ledger-mode)
     (call-interactively #'ledger-report)))
```

Comment: Thank you. Returns `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil (require 'ledger-mode) (ledger-report))`

Comment: Fixed that - can you try again?

Comment: Thank you. Returns `Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 2), 0`

Comment: Eh - sorry. I'm proceeding blindly since I have neither `spacemacs`, nor `ledger-report`, but this "final" fix *should* work (famous last words!)

Comment: Asks `Buffer modified, save it? (y or n)`. Hitting `n`, I'm able to select a report (hurray), though `find-file-noselect: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. Could it help providing the ledger file as an argument to your snippet?

Comment: It might but I cannot test that without installing `ledger` and `ledger-report` and I don't have time to do that. Feel free to experiment and edit the answer if you get it working (or provide your own answer, or wait until somebody with a properly equipped emacs can provide a correct answer). I'll leave the answer up for a little while for inspiration :-) but if a correct answer is provided by somebody, I'll delete it.